# Pycharm doesn't show image(matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

This code, doesn't show image:

```
plt.imshow(Image.open(img_paths[0]))
```

Maybe i need a pro version?

Comment: try `plt.show()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works in PyCharm. The image is displayed in a new window. I copied my image named image.png into my PyCharm project's venv folder so that PyCharm would find it automatically. Instead of pasting an image named image.png into your PyCharm project's venv folder, you could do the same with your list named img_paths.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

fname = 'image.png'
plt.imshow(Image.open(fname))
plt.show()
```

**Note:** PyCharm does not automatically find your globally installed Python packages unless the project has been configured to find them. To do this select the *Inherit global-site packages* option when you create a new project.

Select *File* -> *New Project* to create a new project. Click the triangle marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot to show the new project's options.

[image]

Then check the *Inherit global-site packages* checkbox and click the  <kbd>Create</kbd>  button in the lower right corner of the Create Project window.

[image]